# Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a factory class and it has a constructor where dependency injection is implemented. When trying to register the factory method in program.cs file I get the below error when running the application. "Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'Factory".

```
public class Factory : IFactory
{
 private readonly A _a;
    private readonly string _test;

    public Factory(A a, string sample)
    {
        _a= a;
        _test= string.IsNullOrEmpty(sample) ? string.Empty : Path.GetFullPath(sample);
    }

   private string Create(long id)
    {
        var b = _test.make(id);
        return b;
    }
  }
```

In program.cs file how can we register this string element _test? Can anyone help!

Comment: Have you tried something like `services.AddTransient<IFactory>(c => new Factory(c.GetRequiredService<A>(), "sample")`?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your Factory constructor is not parameter-less, and when the service provider tries to instantiate the Factory, it has no value to pass for the "sample" variable.

There are two possible solutions to this:

1- Changing the design of your factory, and passing the "sample" as a variable to Create method instead of the constructor.

OR

2- Registering the factory like this:

```
services.AddSingleton(s => new Factory(s.GetService<A>(), "desired string"));
```

Btw, I don't know what is the use case that you have for implementing this factory class, but it doesn't seem the right way of implementing it. I suggest you take a look at this beforehand:

[Factory Design Pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern)